# Trying to identify the tree in this picture. Shot from the Nepenthe restaurant, Big Sur, California

Tags: species-identification

I'm trying to identify the tree in this picture. This was shot from the Nepenthe restaurant, Big Sur, California.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,
Robert[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to make out the leaves in the photo, but the tree in the foreground appears to be a [coast live oak (*Quercus agrifolia*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_agrifolia).  The tree has hairy [lichen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichen) growing on its branches.

Comment: Thank-you for the quick response. Much appreciated.